# Flask Application: HTML isn't rendering image

Tags: html, file, flask, frontend, filesystems

I'm trying to reference an image that is in my local file system. I'm not sure if I'm referencing it correctly. I've seen other sources use the 'file://' designation before the path.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
   <body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <header>
        <h1>Welcome to our Startup</h1>
        <p>Discover the future with us.</p>
        <a href="/about">Learn More</a>
    </header>
    <div id="image">
        <img src="/Users/myname/Flask_App/Images/Komodo_image.jpeg">
    </div>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using flask's static file serving system.

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of a system file path, which can cause CORS errors, use Flask's built-in static file serving system**

Create a folder in your app's directory called `static`:

```
project root
|___ templates
|    |___ image.jpeg
|___ myapp.py
```

Now modify your html, replacing the line

```
<img src="/Users/myname/Flask_App/Images/Komodo_image.jpeg">
```

with

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='image.jpeg') }}">
```

[Untested, but should work]

For more on Flask and static files see: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/static/